# An ideal that there exists a unique ideal maximal with respect to not containing it

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of a commutative ring with identity. Is there any equivalent condition  to the property that there exists a unique ideal maximal with respect to not containing $I$?

For example if $(R, m)$ is a local ring, then $m$ has this property if and only if $m$ is a principal ideal.